# auto increment id in GetElementsById

Tags: javascript, increment

Please help me out to complete Id increment in getElementById() using loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('idA(increment)').onchange = function () {
     document.getElementById('idB(increment)').value = event.target.value
  }
</script>
```

*instead of*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById(\'idA1\').onchange = function () {
     document.getElementById(\'idB1\').value = event.target.value
  }

  document.getElementById(\'idA2\').onchange = function () {
     document.getElementById(\'idB2\').value = event.target.value
  }

  document.getElementById(\'idA3\').onchange = function () {
     document.getElementById(\'idB3\').value = event.target.value
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just used a class name if you want to target multiple elements to attach functions to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class based lookup to target all the elements and then add the change event handler

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('id-a');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById(this.id.replace(/^idA/, 'idB')).value = event.target.value
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="idA1" class="id-a" />
<input id="idB1" />
<br />
<input id="idA2" class="id-a" />
<input id="idB2" />
<br />
<input id="idA3" class="id-a" />
<input id="idB3" />
<br />
<input id="idA4" class="id-a" />
<input id="idB4" />
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css class and use `document.querySelectorAll('.my-class')`.

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.my-class');

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
  nodes[i].onchange = function() {
    // Do what you want here
  };
}
```

As mentionned by NewToJS, you can also do `var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class')`.

Comment: Or `document.getElementsByClassName('SomeClass');`